# Calculating the Upper and lower limits of boxplot statistic (i.e. end of whiskers)

Tags: r

I'm trying to verify the upper and lower limits of the boxplot statistics (i.e. the end of the whiskers) by comparing it to the formula, Q3+(1.5*IQR) and Q1-(1.5*IQR).

Each time I iterate the following code, it always returns a small difference between the boxplot statistic and the formula.

Shouldn't these numbers be identical?  Why the deviation?

```
# random normal distribution
df <- rnorm(500)
# convert to dataframe
df <- as.data.frame(df)
# boxplot statistics
s <- boxplot.stats(df$df)
s$stats
# Upper limit of whisker: Q3+(1.5*IQR)
s$stats[4]+(1.5*(IQR(df$df)))
# Lower limit of whisker: Q1-(1.5*IQR)
s$stats[2]-(1.5*(IQR(df$df)))
```

Comment: The whiskers extend out to the data that is at *or inside* `Q3+(1.5*IQR)`. Meaning, go out to `Q3*(1.5*IQR)`, and then pull it back until it hits data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whiskers extend out to the data that is at *or inside* `Q3+(1.5*IQR)`. Meaning, go out to `Q3*(1.5*IQR)`, and then pull it back until it hits data.

We can find those values with:

```r
set.seed(42)
vec <- rnorm(500)
st <- boxplot.stats(vec)
st$stats
# [1] -2.46133548 -0.66263842 -0.03797064  0.63573211  2.45959355


###       ,--- data
###       |   ,--- that is at or inside
###       |  |      ,--- this number
###      ,-, v ,----^---------------------,
max(vec[ vec < st$stats[4]+(1.5*(IQR(vec))) ])
# [1] 2.459594

min(vec[ vec > st$stats[2]-(1.5*(IQR(vec))) ])
# [1] -2.461335
```

Comment: What a great explanation!  It finally makes sense.  Wikipedia's explanation goes as follows: "...a distance of 1.5 times the IQR is measured out and a whisker is drawn up to the largest observed data point from the dataset that falls within this distance."  This is not as clear as what you presented.  Thank you.